# Data Field Value is necessary in Jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to Call the ajax without sending any value in data filed. Actually I am getting the required value using session, so I don't need to send any value.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "",
    url:  CLIENT_HTTP_PATH+"withdraw/getajaxwithdrawdetail/",
    dataType: "json",                     
    success: function(data) {

    });
});
```

When I am sending the blank value than i am getting the error **Value does not implement interface Node.** Is that necessary to send the data in ajax?

I looked at the [Manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) but not found that the data is not mandatory.

Comment: This may be sound dumb but... Why a POST and not a GET?

Comment: Post & GET is doesn't Matter,Data filed was blank in my case

Comment: Then do a GET with a simple URL, no data nor payload needed.

Comment: yes that will be the another way to do it, however i have solved issue by @jimbo's answer.

Comment: @STTLCU Has a fair point though - if you're not changing anything server-side, might as well be a get :P

Comment: @HarshalMahajan, yes, you solved the problem, but that was like beating a nail with a rock instead of a hammer.

Comment: @STTLCU :D....okay i can use the GET.You are Right Man..!!

Comment: @HarshalMahajan the point is to use the right tool for the right job. Even if POST and GET are now used almost for the same task, POST has been created to send data to a remote server, for elaboration and storage, while GET was used to retrieve informations from the server, possibly identified by parameters in the querystring. It's just a formality now, but this may help you to understand better WHY there are two methods that do almost the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing a blank array as your data in the following format:

```
array (
    'arr' => array (
        0 => ''
    )
)
```

Comment: Empty Value Did the Job...Thanks..!!

Answer (score 3):

i don't know its a proper method or not, but i've used this 3-4 times and its working.

```
$.post("target.php",{},function(data,success){$('.client_side_target').html(data)}
```

or

```
$.post("target.php",{},function(data,success){$('.client_side_target').append(data)}
```

Comment: `$.post()` _is_ AJAX, it's just a shortcut method that pre-defines some of the fields

Comment: @Harshal Mahajan: you wrote $.ajax({  type: "POST",...});
$.post refers the same and its a shortcut method as mentioned above comment by  Bojangles..

Comment: Ain't there's a missing comma, after `target.php`?